# Diferença entre consulta com e sem Inner Join

Tags: sql-server, sql-select, inner-join

Qual a diferença entre fazer as duas consultas abaixo, uma com e a outra sem INNER JOIN? Qual a mais adequada?

```
SELECT p.Descricao as Produto, c.Descricao as Categoria FROM Produto p, Categoria  c
WHERE p.CategoriaId = c.CategoriaId
```

```
SELECT p.Descricao as Produto, c.Descricao as Categoria  FROM Produto p
INNER JOIN Categoria c ON p.CategoriaId = c.CategoriaId
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De forma geral podemos dizer que é a sintaxe apenas. Uma sintaxe que deixa mais claro o que deseja fazer uma junção pode ser mais interessante pela legibilidade.

É possível que algum mecanismo de banco de dados faça alguma otimização em algum caso que ela não consegue em outro. Pode até ser uma deficiência dele não conseguir fazer nos dois casos, mas pode correr. Tem que ver como isso se comporta no seu SGDB.

E atente porque pode não ser igual em todas situações, alguns farão uma otimização em todas situações, mas não em todas. Pra isso existe o [`EXPLAIN`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/explain-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) na maioria dos bancos.